Unable to view the data in the response of Prometheus query, only response code is shown
I am sending a GET request on the prometheus https endpoint using Postman.
I am getting below result.
:
I can see the response code is 200 OK , it means the query work.
result field is empty. I want the result as well, when i query in the grafana i can see the data.

Please include the query

You need to give more information. query or query_range? url in postman and setting in grafana. From the picture, the returned is OK, so query is different
